# R: How to fix errors in specific dataset rows by using ifelse() function or other methods

Tags: r, if-statement, error-handling

My dataset contains the following typos

```
unique(d$gender)
[1] "k"           "kobieta"     "M"           "K"           "m─Ö┼╝czyzna" "21"          "m"           "M─Ö┼╝czyzna"

> unique(d$age)
[1] 19 NA 21 20 30 32 22 25 29
```

Actually, rows with 21 for gender and NA for age have been switched and moreover, different naming have been used for gender variable (indeed, all the 'k' heading name corresponds to female 'F' and the heading one with 'm' stand for male 'M'). I've written down this command lines to fix this for gender variable:

```
> d$gender = ifelse(d$gender == 'K', 'F', 
+            ifelse(d$gender =='kobieta', 'F', ifelse(d$gender == 'k', 'F', 
+            ifelse(d$gender == "m-Ö++czyzna", 'M',ifelse(d$gender == '21', 'M',
+            ifelse(d$gender == 'm', 'M', ifelse(d$gender == 'M-Ö++czyzna', 'M', 
+            ifelse(d$gender == 'M', 'M', 'M'))))))))
> 
> unique(d$gender)
[1] "F" "M"
```

But I don't know how to do he same for age variable, neither if this method could be the right way. Anyone has any suggestions?

This is the dput() result:

```
dput(head(d,50))
structure(list(ID = c("P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", 
"P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", 
"P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", 
"P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", 
"P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", 
"P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", 
"P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", 
"P1323", "P1323", "P1323"), gender = c("F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F"), age = c(19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 
19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 
19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 
19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19), fixation_time = c(60, 
60, 60, 60, 60, 70, 50, 50, 50, 70, 70, 60, 50, 60, 70, 70, 50, 
70, 70, 60, 70, 50, 50, 50, 60, 70, 60, 50, 60, 70, 60, 70, 50, 
60, 70, 50, 50, 70, 70, 70, 70, 50, 60, 50, 60, 60, 70, 50, 60, 
60), block = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    t1.key = c("None", "None", "None", "space", "None", "space", 
    "None", "None", "None", "space", "None", "None", "space", 
    "None", "None", "space", "None", "None", "space", "None", 
    "space", "space", "space", "None", "None", "None", "space", 
    "space", "None", "None", "space", "None", "None", "None", 
    "None", "None", "None", "space", "space", "None", "None", 
    "None", "None", "space", "None", "None", "space", "None", 
    "space", "None"), T1.response = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), COND = c("NR", 
    "NR", "NR", "R", "NR", "R", "NR", "NR", "NR", "R", "NR", 
    "NR", "R", "NR", "NR", "R", "NR", "NR", "R", "NR", "R", "R", 
    "R", "NR", "NR", "NR", "R", "R", "NR", "NR", "R", "NR", "NR", 
    "NR", "NR", "NR", "NR", "R", "R", "NR", "NR", "NR", "NR", 
    "R", "NR", "NR", "R", "NR", "R", "NR"), T1.rt = c(NA, NA, 
    NA, 0.812299799988978, NA, 0.72336569998879, NA, NA, NA, 
    0.772733500052709, NA, NA, 0.606754800013732, NA, NA, 0.601030899968464, 
    NA, NA, 0.838272600027267, NA, 0.305548300035298, 0.849945599969942, 
    0.748269900039304, NA, NA, NA, 0.859215400007088, 0.95704890001798, 
    NA, NA, 0.874362500035204, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.270455699996091, 
    0.75726039998699, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.762694000033662, NA, 
    NA, 0.789715700026136, NA, 0.90579859999707, NA), CR.key = c("p", 
    "p", "p", "p", "p", "p", "p", "p", "p", "p", "p", "p", "p", 
    "p", "o", "p", "i", "i", "h", "u", "i", "u", "o", "o", "p", 
    "p", "p", "o", "p", "i", "o", "p", "p", "p", "o", "o", "o", 
    "p", "i", "p", "p", "o", "o", "i", "i", "o", "o", "i", "i", 
    "u"), CR.rt = c(0.651771800010465, 0.585048799985088, 0.652350199990906, 
    0.69888829998672, 1.01917029998731, 0.550036200031173, 0.0361186999944039, 
    0.568817299965303, 0.452191599993966, 0.514980700041633, 
    0.619590600021184, 0.719264700019266, 0.466181399999186, 
    0.45217840000987, 0.668881699966732, 0.914478300022893, 1.01910460001091, 
    1.40315000002738, 1.69993370003067, 1.71914210001705, 1.29938790004235, 
    0.698139799991623, 0.848338100011461, 0.651829700043891, 
    0.486136299965438, 0.703567499993369, 0.76673849998042, 0.54929809999885, 
    0.718664799991529, 0.768383099988569, 0.898415500007104, 
    0.819344500021543, 0.61898209998617, 0.737225699995179, 1.03654629999073, 
    0.971092400024645, 1.4362695000018, 0.999490200018045, 0.932840399967972, 
    0.586312200000975, 0.786785800009966, 1.01987839996582, 0.93673920002766, 
    0.715710600023158, 0.819960499997251, 0.75370900001144, 0.818668299994897, 
    0.903600800025742, 1.1176545000053, 1.10352450003847), trial_num = c(0, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 17, 18, 19, 
    20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 
    36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 
    52, 53), ldots = c(48, 48, 52, 55, 51, 51, 52, 49, 45, 55, 
    49, 49, 51, 49, 48, 52, 45, 49, 45, 55, 51, 48, 55, 51, 45, 
    45, 52, 48, 48, 48, 55, 51, 49, 48, 49, 51, 51, 55, 51, 49, 
    45, 55, 51, 55, 55, 52, 52, 48, 49, 52), rdots = c(52, 52, 
    48, 45, 49, 49, 48, 51, 55, 45, 51, 51, 49, 51, 52, 48, 55, 
    51, 55, 45, 49, 52, 45, 49, 55, 55, 48, 52, 52, 52, 45, 49, 
    51, 52, 51, 49, 49, 45, 49, 51, 55, 45, 49, 45, 45, 48, 48, 
    52, 51, 48), TASK = c("left", "left", "left", "left", "left", 
    "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", 
    "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", 
    "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", 
    "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", 
    "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", 
    "left", "left", "left", "left", "left"), T1.correct = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    Go.Nogo..whether.a.person.should.respond. = c("NR", "NR", 
    "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "NR", "NR", "R", "NR", "NR", "R", 
    "NR", "NR", "R", "NR", "NR", "NR", "R", "R", "NR", "R", "R", 
    "NR", "NR", "R", "NR", "NR", "NR", "R", "R", "NR", "NR", 
    "NR", "R", "R", "R", "R", "NR", "NR", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
    "R", "R", "NR", "NR", "R"), T1.ACC = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), CR = structure(c(4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
    2L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "9"), class = "factor"), 
    difficulty = c("medium", "medium", "medium", "easy", "hard", 
    "hard", "medium", "hard", "easy", "easy", "hard", "hard", 
    "hard", "hard", "medium", "medium", "easy", "hard", "easy", 
    "easy", "hard", "medium", "easy", "hard", "easy", "easy", 
    "medium", "medium", "medium", "medium", "easy", "hard", "hard", 
    "medium", "hard", "hard", "hard", "easy", "hard", "hard", 
    "easy", "easy", "hard", "easy", "easy", "medium", "medium", 
    "medium", "hard", "medium")), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your data with `dput()`

Comment: Also I did not understand what is wrong with age

Comment: I am just not able to figure out a concrete method to replace if with that 21 under gender column.

Comment: dataset is pretty big. I am not able to gather every single observation with dput().

Comment: if you have another method, I can use that one.

Comment: `dput(head(d,50))` The first 50 observations of your data, where d is the name of your data.frame

Comment: Just in case you would like to try, I redited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which is the problem with the Age. But the ifelse statement can be rewritten in the next way:

If there are no anomalies in the `d$gender` field:

```
d$gender2 = ifelse(tolower(substr(d$gender,1,1)) == "k", "F", "M")
```

If there are anomalies in the `d$gender` field:

```
d$gender2 = ifelse(tolower(substr(d$gender,1,1)) == "k", "F",
                   ifelse(tolower(substr(d$gender,1,1)) == "m" | d$gender == "21", "M", "Other")
```

I think that is a more comfortable method. and you could use some variation like this.

In the case of the Age I don't know what you want to do.

Comment: Absolutely useful. Many thanks that was very helpful. Could you please describe shortly the function tolower and what it does? Thanks again.

Comment: `tolower()` makes every character from a string lower-case. `toupper()` makes every character from a string to upper-case. Try looking at the documentation writing `?tolower`. Glad to help you. If you are satisfied with my answer you can upvote it. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to introduce you to two things: the `%in%` operator and the `datastep()` function.

The `%in%` operator lets you consolidate possible matches into a vector.  So you can do `x %in% c(y, z)` instead of `ifelse(x == y, a, ifelse(x == z, a, x))`. It can greatly reduce the number of nested conditions.

Second, I wrote a package called [libr](https://libr.r-sassy.org/) that has a function called `datastep()` that was specifically designed for cleaning data like you are trying to do.  It is appropriate for situations when you have a lot of nested conditions and complicated logic.  It loops through the data row by row, lets you examine the values on each row, and create new values based on the values of a particular row.  The best thing is you can nest the conditionals as deep as you want and still read them.

Here is an example using both `%in%` and the `datastep()` function:

```
library(libr)

# Sample data
d <- data.frame(gender = c("k", "kobieta", "M", "K", "m─Ö┼╝czyzna", "21", "m", "M─Ö┼╝czyzna", "F"),
                age = c(19, NA, 21, 20, 30, 32, 22, 25, 29))

# Define datastep
d2 <- datastep(d, {
  
    if (gender %in% c('K', 'k', 'kobieta', 'f')) {
      gender_corrected <- 'F'
    } else if (gender %in% c('m', 'm─Ö┼╝czyzna', 'M─Ö┼╝czyzna')) {
      gender_corrected <- 'M'
    } else if (gender == 21) {
      gender_corrected <- 'M'
    } else {
      gender_corrected <- gender 
    }
      
    if (is.na(age)) {
      # Do something
    } else {
      if (age < 10) {
        # Do something else 
      } else {
        age_corrected <- age
      }
    }
  
  
  })
```

So the result d2 would look like this:

```
> d2
       gender age age_corrected gender_corrected
1           k  19            19                F
2     kobieta  NA            NA                F
3           M  21            21                M
4           K  20            20                F
5 m-Ö++czyzna  30            30                M
6          21  32            32                M
7           m  22            22                M
8 M-Ö++czyzna  25            25                M
9           F  29            29                F
```

Comment: This is a genial and useful function to run. Thank you!! Pretty useful and instructive as well.

Comment: However, I've tried to run it as it is but after checking results by unique(d$gender) function that returns always the same errors.

Comment: The corrected genders are in d$gender_corrected.  I was expecting you to understand what is happening and modify the conditionals for your needs.

Comment: I considered it but actually I am not able to figure this problem out. I'm keeping on returing back this error.